# Is there a Mellin transform or an analogue on $L^2([0,2\pi])$ or $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms, mellin-transform

From Wikipedia, the Mellin transform is an isometry $M : L^2(\mathbb{R}^+) \mapsto L^2(\mathbb{R})$,

$$\{M f\} (s) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^+} x^{-1/2 + \mathrm{i} s} f(x) dx.$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform

Does anyone know if there is an analogue of this transformation on $L^2([0,2\pi])$ or $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ ?

Thanks !

Comment: I mean, the mellin transform is basically the fourier transofrm on the group $\mathbb{R^+}$ (I think), and there are fourier transforms for $[0,2\pi]$ and $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: The analogue is the map $f\in L^2(0, 2\pi)\mapsto (\hat{f}(n))_{n\in\mathbb Z}\in \ell^2$. Here $\hat{f}(n):=\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)\exp(-inx)\, dx.$ Notice that this is also a surjective isometry.

Comment: The Mellin transform is the Fourier/Pontryagin transform on $\Bbb{R}_{> 0},\times$ and it is an isometry $L^2(\Bbb{R}_{> 0}, \frac{dx}{x}) \to L^2(\Bbb{R})$ (where $\frac{dx}{x}$ is the Haar measure of the group). The Fourier series is the Fourier/Pontryagin transform of $\Bbb{R/Z}$, the analogue for the Mellin transform is the Fourier/Pontryagin transform of $(\Bbb{R}_{> 0},\times)/2^\Bbb{Z}$ which is isometric to $\ell^2(\Bbb{Z})$. @mathworker21

Comment: @ Giuseppe Negro : so you are saying that in this context the Mellin transform and the Fourier transform are the same thing. Correct ? @ reuns : thanks for your answer, i'm not familiar with the Pontryagin transform that you refer to, is it possible to write it out in closed form it it's only abstract ? thanks to all !

Comment: The idea of the Fourier/Pontryagin transform is, for a (locally compact) abelian group, to send $f \in L^2(G)$ to $F(\chi) =  \int_G f(x) \chi(x)d\mu(x)$ for each character $\chi$ from $ G $ to the complex unit circle (with $\mu$ the Haar measure).

Comment: Hi reuns, thanks for your help, i really appreciate it. I apologize however because you are going a bit fast for me. What is the isometry that maps $(\mathbb{R}_{>0},\times)/2^{\mathbb{Z}}$ to $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ ? it is possible to write it down or how is it constructed ? do you have any useful references for this because I still don't quite see it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f \in L^2_{loc}( \Bbb{R}_{>0} )$ such that $f(2x) = f(x)$. Then we have the Fourier series $$f =\sum_n C_n(f) x^{2i \pi n/\log(2)} = \sum_n C_n(f) e^{2i \pi n\log_2(x) }, \quad C_n(f) = \frac{1}{\log(2)}\int_1^2 f(x) e^{-2i \pi n\log_2(x) }\frac{dx}{x}$$

Comment: thank you very much reuns ! i really appreciate your insight